# Convert MySQL's POINT to text in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, gis, geospatial

Using PHP, how can I convert a value in `POINT` datatype to a string like `POINT (-34.601020 -58.371020)` (an ouput in WKT or GeoJSON is preferable)

If I echo the raw value, I get weird characters.

I've tried using `bin2hex` and then tried to convert the hex to string but with no luck.

I'm aware of MySQL's `AsText()`, but I would like to do it in PHP.

Comment: Why not use the `AsText` function? MySQL's internal format for this isn't something PHP should ever need to understand. Keep your concerns separated.

Comment: @tadman Let's say I cannot change the code where the query is created, so I trying to handmade the `AsText` function in PHP

Comment: This could be a fight you can't win. Best of luck.

Comment: @tadman well....I won! =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally I've got this working!!!

I had to use [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) in order to extract the binary data from MySQL

```
$point_value = $data_from_db["point_field"];

$coordinates = unpack('x/x/x/x/corder/Ltype/dlon/dlat', $point_value);

echo $coordinates['lat'];
echo $coordinates['lon'];
```

[Here](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/) is a tutotial that helped me with this issue

Comment: Its possible to simplify x/x/x/x: $coordinates = unpack('x4/corder/Ltype/dlat/dlon', $point_value);
And since order/type is not required, its possible to 'mask' both:
$coordinates = unpack('x4/clat/Llat/dlat/dlon', $point_value);

Comment: Point format is (Long,Lat)  or (X,Y), not (Lat,Long).... so the correct format for unpack is 'x4/corder/Ltype/dlon/dlat'