# Converting MYSQL Polygon to text in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[Convert MySQL's POINT to text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467050/convert-mysqls-point-to-text-in-php/43544958#43544958)

I found this question & answer and it solved my problems.
But I haven't found a solution for polygons.

Does someone have a solution to convert the blob/polygon to text similar to the point example?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ST_NumGeometries(from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-geometrycollection-property-functions.html#function_st-numgeometries) it should give you the number of points and then you could to use a loop and ST_GeometryN to fetch each individual point.  This would still need to be decoded like you already have.

You could convert the polygon back to text (AsText) and then parse the data there.

Comment: Is there a way without mysql?

Comment: As the data varies according to the number of points, it would be difficult.  BUT you would also leave yourself open to changes in the internals of the database - they change one small thing and your code will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

As you know MySQl (and MariDB) store geometry data as follow:

> MySQL stores geometry values using 4 bytes to indicate the SRID followed by the WKB representation of the value. For a description of WKB format, see Well-Known Binary (WKB) Format.

[See MySQL documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-internal-format) for more information.

By using GeoPHP you could convert any Geo data (from my MySQL) as follow:

```
$data = unpack("lsrid/H*wkb", $val);
$wkb_reader = new WKB();
$geometry = $wkb_reader->read($data['wkb'], TRUE);
$wkt_writer = new WKT();
$wkt = $wkt_writer->write($geometry);
return $wkt;
```

Where $val is column value from MySQL table.

The first line unpack data into two part:

1- SRID: first 4 bytes
2- WKB: Others as hex strig

and convert WKB hex string into WKT with GeoPHP.

Comment: Thx i will try this!

Comment: This should be accepted answer. @Mostafa any hint to do opposite? convert wkb to mysql format?

Comment: This is a common way. I usually use it to convert data in views. Do you have any idea? @mihkelo