# GeoPHP Exception to convert mydql WKB Only NDR (little endian) SKB format is supported at the moment

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read mysql POINT column and convert it into WKT. As you know data format of GEOMETRY in MySQL is WKB so to convert with GeoPHP you should:

```
$wkb_reader = new WKB();
$geometry = $wkb_reader->read($val,FALSE);
$wkt_writer = new WKT();
$wkt = $wkt_writer->write(oGeometry);
```

Where $val is an BLOB (array of bytes).

It face with error (while reading data):

```
Exception: Only NDR (little endian) SKB format is supported at the moment
```

EDIT:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467050/convert-mysqls-point-to-text-in-php) is the same problem but the $val may be a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know MySQl (and MariDB) store geometry data as follow:

> MySQL stores geometry values using 4 bytes to indicate the SRID followed by the WKB representation of the value. For a description of WKB format, see Well-Known Binary (WKB) Format.

[See MySQL documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-internal-format) for more information.

So, first 4 bytes are SRID and must removed from data. You could convert any Geo data (from my MySQL) as follow:

```
$data = unpack("lsrid/H*wkb", $val);
$wkb_reader = new WKB();
$geometry = $wkb_reader->read($data['wkb'], TRUE);
$wkt_writer = new WKT();
$wkt = $wkt_writer->write($geometry);
return $wkt;
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089036/635891